# Uploading an image makes base64 data

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am using `<input type="file">` to upload an image to my website, it works fine but the image is always encrypted to base64 as a bunch of jammed up random characters. this is causing lag for me when there is a lot of images and this takes longer to upload and receive from the server.

Is there a better way to upload an image? and to not have it in base64?
This is the code that I am using for displaying the image on the page

```
oFReader = new FileReader(), rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;

oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
// var ID is predefined
    document.getElementById(ID).innerHTML = `
    <image src="${oFREvent.target.result}" width="200px" height="200px" ></image>`;
};

function loadImageFile() {

    if (document.getElementById("uploadImage").files.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
    var oFile = document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0];
    if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) { alert("You must select a valid image file!"); return; }
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `URL.createObjectURL(File);` to create a url for the file (image) you want to display, then use it in the src attribute to display it.

```js
oFReader = new FileReader(), rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;

function loadImageFile() {
    if (document.getElementById("uploadImage").files.length === 0) { return; }

    var oFile = document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0];
    if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) { alert("You must select a valid image file!"); return; }
    
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(oFile);
    img.width = 200;
    img.height = 200;
    img.onload = function() {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
    }
    document.getElementById(ID).appendChild(img);
}
```

for a better understanding of what's going on check the docs

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example_Using_object_URLs_to_display_images